# Size of precompiled assets has increased a lot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am working on an rails app in which I precompiled assets multiple times.

I precompiled them again and again as with changes in **.js** and **.css** files, mostly for production but couple of times for development too.

using `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

What I have noticed is that, actual size of my assets is **5 MB**.

But when I see my precompiled assets in `public/assets`, its size is almost **125 MB**.

Why its size has increased & what I am suppose to do to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete public/assets folder and try again rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production. Hope will help.

Comment: I think you have old assets. (rake assets:clean # Remove old compiled assets)

Comment: rake assets:clean was was little old
for rails 4+ "rake assets:clobber" is used.
However thanks man